# Is that possible to find width and height of an image using PHP DOM?

Tags: php, html, image, dom

I scrap a webpage content using curl. And create DOM using that html content. I need to check size of the images that contained in that html.

Is that possible to width and height of an using Php DOM (image tag not containing the width and height attribute)?

Comment: You might be also interested in [How to determine the size of an image without downloading it (in full)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7452896/367456) and similar Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are saying img tag is not containing height & width.  You can look at [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)  PHP function. You need to pass image url you getting from scrapping to getimagesize function.

Ex:

```
<?php 

   $size = getimagesize("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif");          

   print_r($size);
?>
```

**OUTPUT** is array

```
Array
(
[0] => 120
[1] => 67
[2] => 1
[3] => width="120" height="67"
[bits] => 7
[channels] => 3
[mime] => image/gif
)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is the only way I think , and its works fine. Thank you friend