# How to get an image size from URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use below way to get an image size from a URL:

```
const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const imageSize = {
                    x: img.width,
                    y: img.height
                };
                resolve(imageSize);
            };

            img.src = imageUrl;
```

basically it loads the whole image and determine its size. I wonder there is any other way to get it without downloading the full image. Is there a header I can load to read the image's size?

Comment: I don't think that that is possible. The image dimensions are encoded as part of the image itself.

Comment: Though there are [some interesting ideas in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452896/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-image-without-downloading-it-in-full) worth reading.

Comment: Do you have controll over the server at which the images are stored?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I don't think the answer you marked is necessarily true. It *is* possible to get the dimensions without downloading the *full* image. The solution may not be elegant or practical but it's definitely possible.

Comment: @Marty I saw the link you posted. I guess in javascript, downloading the image a 100 times would be better than to use any of those solutions. There aren't any javascript libraries that parses image formats that I know of, and if they exist they won't cover each image format and they will require much work and overhead.

Comment: Like I said; the solution won't be nice but saying it's not possible is false.

Comment: For jpeg you'll need the whole file for png, gif, bmp the 22 firsts bits should be enough. You can find such a parser from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540903/sort-by-image-resolution-in-gallery/42649964#42649964 where we used a file input, but you can very well replace it with a xhr range request.