# How can I use php to check another server's speed?

Tags: php, performance, curl

Using PHP, I would like to download 50mb of a 1gb movie file to check if the upload speed of server hosting the movie goes to at least 100kB/s in that exact moment.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to CURLOPT_RANGE to grab a specific section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048158/alternative-to-curlopt-range-to-grab-a-specific-section)

Comment: is not clear if you want to check a download speed, if you want to limit a download or if you just want to download a movie :/

Comment: @Gianps updated the question to be more precise

Comment: @ceejayoz not even close

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl_setopt` with the `CURLOPT_RANGE` option.

Comment: I`m not sure about how to use it for what I need. Could you share an example?

Comment: It is completely up to the server to decide whether to respect the range request, i.e., not reliable. I would suggest using fsockopen() and stream the content until n bytes were received.

Comment: Use `microtime` to figure out the start and end times, subtract the end from the start to get the number of seconds, figure out how many bytes per seconds you wound up with.

Comment: really no other better solutions, anyone?